# WordPress - How to Disable a filter used by media.php from function.php?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

In WordPress if I add "Photo Gallery" to my theme template using this code:

```
              <?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery link="file"]'); ?>
```

Then WordPress Core will "use_default_gallery_style" cause its set to "**true**" in:

> **wp-include/media.php line 755 starts like:**

```
if ( apply_filters( 'use_default_gallery_style', true ) )
    $gallery_style = "
    <style type='text/css'>
        #{$selector} {
            margin: auto;
        }
        #{$selector} .gallery-item {
            float: {$float};
            margin-top: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            width: {$itemwidth}%;
        }
        #{$selector} img {
            border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
        }
        #{$selector} .gallery-caption {
            margin-left: 0;
        }
        /* see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php */
    </style>";
$size_class = sanitize_html_class( $size );
$gallery_div = "<div id='$selector' class='gallery galleryid-{$id} gallery-columns-{$columns} gallery-size-{$size_class}'>";
$output = apply_filters( 'gallery_style', $gallery_style . "\n\t\t" . $gallery_div );
```

**The problem is:** The HTML code for my page will NOT get validated by online HTML validators cause WordPress Core prints CSS in HTML page, it's not using a separated CSS file which is the right way to do.

The CODE WordPress outputs to HTML looks like:

```
<style type='text/css'>
            #gallery-1 {
                margin: auto;
            }
            #gallery-1 .gallery-item {
                float: left;
                margin-top: 10px;
                text-align: center;
                width: 33%;
            }
            #gallery-1 img {
                border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
            }
            #gallery-1 .gallery-caption {
                margin-left: 0;
            }
            /* see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php */
        </style>
```

**My solution for now:**

I know its NOT recommended to EDIT WordPress CORE files! BUT I have edited wp-include/media.php line 755

**From:**

```
     if ( apply_filters( 'use_default_gallery_style', true ) )
```

**To:**

```
     if ( apply_filters( 'use_default_gallery_style', false ) )
```

**And I have updated/added this to my style.css:**

```
        #gallery-1 {
            margin: auto;
        }
        #gallery-1 .gallery-item {
            float: left;
            margin-top: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 33%;
        }
        #gallery-1 img {
            border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
        }
        #gallery-1 .gallery-caption {
            margin-left: 0;
        }
```

**My question:** How can I set filter: use_default_gallery_style to false using function.php?

How to write a hook, function or action in function.php to remove or set use_default_gallery_style to false?

Whats the best way to do it?

Im new and don't want to mess with WordPress CORE files, it would be great if someone can help me or guide me with this function.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about WordPress, belongs to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
add_filter( 'use_default_gallery_style', '__return_false' );
```

as suggested here: http://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/wordpress-media-gallery-please-that-cant-be-true/page/6